# How do I access the link data in an xml node in python?

Tags: python, xml, nodes

I have the following kind of data returned to me in xml format (many rooms are returned; this is one example of the data I get back):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rooms>
    <total-results>1</total-results>
    <items-per-page>1</items-per-page>
    <start-index>0</start-index>
    <room>
        <id>xxxxxxxx</id>
        <etag>5</etag>
        <link rel="http://schemas.com.mysite.building" title="building" href="https://mysite.me.myschool.edu:8443/ess/scheduleapi/v1/buildings/yyyyyyyyy"/>
        <name>1.306</name>
        <status>active</status>
        <link rel="self" title="self" href="https://mysite.me.myschool.edu:8443/ess/scheduleapi/v1/rooms/aaaaaaaaa">
    </room>
</rooms>
```

If nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE, I seem to be able to access the data (so I can see that I have room 1.306).  Also, I seem to be able to access the nodeName *link*, but I really need to know if that room is in one of my acceptable buildings, so I need to be able to get to the rest of that line to look at the yyyyyyyyy.  Can someone please advise?

OK, @vezult, here is what I finally came up with (working code!) using ElementTree, as you suggested.  This is probably not the most pythonic (or ElementTree-ic?) way of doing this, but it seems to work.  I'm thrilled to have access now to .tag, .attrib, and .text of every piece of my xml.  I welcome any advice on how to make it better.

```
# We start out knowing our room name and our building id.  However, the same room can exist in many buildings.
# Examine the rooms we've received and get the id of the one with our name that is also in our building.

# Query the API for a list of rooms, getting u back.

request = build_request(resourceUrl)
u = urllib2.urlopen(request.to_url())
mydata = u.read()

root = ElementTree.fromstring(mydata)
print 'tree root', root.tag, root.attrib, root.text
for child in root:
    if child.tag == 'room':   
        for child2 in child:
            # the id tag comes before the name tag, so hold on to it
            if child2.tag == "id":
                hold_id = child2.text
            # the building link comes before the room name, so hold on to it
            if child2.tag == 'link':                            # if this is a link
                if "building" in child2.attrib['href']:         # and it's a building link
                    hold_link_data = child2.attrib['href']
            if child2.tag == 'name':
                if (out_bldg in hold_link_data and  # the building link we're looking at has our building in it  
                    (in_rm == child2.text)):        # and this room name is our room name
                    out_rm = hold_id
                    break  # get out of for-loop
```

Comment: You're trying to get an attribute of the node, not the text.  The code you use to do this will depend on the module that you're using to view the xml. So, yes.  Post your current code.

Comment: Your XML is invalid. There is no closing tag for the 2nd link element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provide no indication of what library you are using, so I'm assuming you are using the standard python `ElementTree` module. In that case, do the following:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.fromstring("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rooms>
    <total-results>1</total-results>
    <items-per-page>1</items-per-page>
    <start-index>0</start-index>
    <room>
        <id>xxxxxxxx</id>
        <etag>5</etag>
        <link rel="http://schemas.com.mysite.building" title="building" href="https://mysite.me.myschool.edu:8443/ess/scheduleapi/v1/buildings/yyyyyyyyy" />
        <name>1.306</name>
        <status>active</status>
        <link rel="self" title="self" href="https://mysite.me.myschool.edu:8443/ess/scheduleapi/v1/rooms/aaaaaaaaa" />
    </room>
</rooms>
""")

# Select the first link element in the example XML
for node in tree.findall('./room/link[@title="building"]'):
    # the 'attrib' attribute is a dictionary containing the node attributes
    print node.attrib['href']
```

Comment: I think it should be `print node.attrib['href']` based on, "so I need to be able to get to the rest of that line to look at the yyyyyyyyy", but +1.

Comment: I am a little further along--thanks @vezult!  I was using from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString, but I don't mind trying ElementTree (and in fact, now that I look at the documentation, I probably should.  However, on my print statement, I am now getting an error.  Here's my code: u = urllib2.urlopen(request.to_url())
data = u.read()
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(data)

for treenode in tree.findall('./room/link[@title="building"]'):
    print treenode.attrib['href']
endfor 
 
And I am getting the following error:

Comment: @vezult cont'd
 
And I am getting the following error:
C:\Python26\Lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py in __init__
    "expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)

Comment: @HelenM: Please don't try to expand the scope of your problem in comments. Add your current code (as many have requested), and any errors you encountered in the question itself.